# Black spots in viewfinder and some faded AF points in a month old DSLR - What should I do?

Tags: canon

I have a problem with my new Canon EOS 700D. It hasn't even lasted a month since I bought it and have got this problem.

I noticed yesterday that when I look in the viewfinder I see some black points in the corners and the AF points kind of faded. Only the three bottom points are looking normal, but I barely see the others, including some white points/lines (dirt) appearing in the screen.

Comment: find your receipt and go to the shop

Comment: Regarding the af points i mean the af lights are not showing as normal, only the 3 in the bottom,

Answer (score 1):

Do you ever detach/swap lenses?  I ask because it could be dust or dirt that has gotten inside the mirrorbox assembly.  Get a rocket blower and give the mirror and also the screen  above the mirror a good blast with air.  Do the back of the lens too while you're at it.

The AF points being 'faded' could be some sort of condensation within the pentamirror itself?  This shouldn't happen.  Do you live in a particularly humid part of the world?  Has the camera been exposed to moisture? (Rain, etc?)

Either way - if blowing the inside with a rocket blower doesn't clear the dirt and dust, then as someone said in a comment on your question, take it back to the store with your receipt and get a replacement.

Comment: Dirt and dust can also get in between the focusing screen and the pentamirror. Since it is only visible in the viewfinder and does not show in the image recorded by the sensor, it is usually more trouble (and risk) than it is worth to try and clean it.

Comment: I've took it to the store, they wont replace it, and they said that the will send it to the service center to check if its manufacture problem and they will decide if it get fixed or getting replaced. I hope the replace it!